# How to serialize and save an object to database as Xml using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, xml-serialization

I were using  FileStream to Serialize an Object to Xml and Save to the disk

```
Stream str = new FileStream(@"serializedstate.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GridState));
x.Serialize(str, new GridState
        {
            GridName= txtGridName.Text,
            GridColumns = GetGridColumnStates()
        });
```

This works fine and Xml file is generated on disk. How do I save serialized Object as Xml into a Sql Server 2008 database's XML column using Linq to SQL? And how to deserialize the same from database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To serialize into an XElement

```
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GridState));
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();

        using (XmlWriter xw = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            x.Serialize(xw, new GridState
                {
                    GridName= txtGridName.Text,
                    GridColumns = GetGridColumnStates()
                });
            xw.Close();
        }

        XElement el = doc.Root;
```

To deserialize

```
        using (XmlReader xr = el.CreateReader())
        {
            GridState myDeserializedObject = x.Deserialize(xr) as GridState;
            xr.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql you must have colum type XML and in linq the type of Colum must be XElement than you can manipulate throw Linq.