# Pass List as XElement to be used as XML Datatype parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ParseXML (@InputXML xml)
```

The data type for input parameter  is “xml”.

In the LINQ to SQL generated code for the stored procedure the input parameter is System.Xml.Linq.XElement

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.ParseXML")]
public ISingleResult<ParseXMLResult> ParseXML([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="InputXML", DbType="Xml")] System.Xml.Linq.XElement inputXML)
```

Now, how can I pass the following List to the ParseXML method to make the stored procedure work?

**EDIT**:

After reading the answer - another solution is listed below

```
XElement root = new XElement("ArrayOfBankAccountDTOForStatus",
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"));


foreach (var element in bankAccountDTOList)
{

 XElement ex= new XElement("BankAccountDTOForStatus", 
                      new XElement("BankAccountID", element.BankAccountID),
                      new XElement("Status", element.Status));


 root.Add(ex);
}
```

---

CODE In Question

```
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LibraryReservationSystem;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        var theDataContext = new DBML_Project.MyDataClassesDataContext(connectionstring);

        List<DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus> bankAccountDTOList = new List<DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus>();
        DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus presentAccount1 = new DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus();
        presentAccount1.BankAccountID = 5;
        presentAccount1.Status = "FrozenF13";

        DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus presentAccount2 = new DTOLayer.BankAccountDTOForStatus();
        presentAccount2.BankAccountID = 6;
        presentAccount2.Status = "FrozenF23";
        bankAccountDTOList.Add(presentAccount1);
        bankAccountDTOList.Add(presentAccount2);

        //theDataContext.ParseXML(inputXML);
```

**Required XML Structure**

[image]

Note: This XML is used for some operations, not for directly storing in database as XML. I need to write a select query that will list the data from the XML.

**Stored Procedure Logic**

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (RowNumber int, BankAccountID int, StatusVal varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @MyTable(RowNumber, BankAccountID,StatusVal)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.value('BankAccountID[1]','int') ASC) AS Row,
    c.value('BankAccountID[1]','int'),
    c.value('Status[1]','varchar(32)')
FROM
    @inputXML.nodes('//BankAccountDTOForStatus') T(c);
```

**READING**

1. [How to serialize and save an object to database as Xml using Linq to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825124/how-to-serialize-and-save-an-object-to-database-as-xml-using-linq-to-sql)
2. [How to use a LINQ query to get XElement values when XElements have same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890313/how-to-use-a-linq-query-to-get-xelement-values-when-xelements-have-same-name)
3. [Linq-to-SQL With XML Database Fields -- Why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689772/linq-to-sql-with-xml-database-fields-why-does-this-work)
4. http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=176385

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn your list into an XML fragment like this:

```
        IEnumerable<XElement> el = list.Select(i => 
                            new XElement("BankAccountDTOForStatus", 
                              new XElement("BankAccountID", i.BankAccountID),
                              new XElement("Status", i.Status)
                            ));
```

Then you can turn it into an XElement:

```
        XElement root = new XElement("root", el);
```

Now you can just pass it to ParseXML as parameter inputXML which is of type XElement.
In stored procedure handle it like this:

```
DECLARE @InputXML NVARCHAR(1024) = N'
<root>
 <BankAccountDTOForStatus>
     <BankAccountID>2</BankAccountID>
     <Status>FrozenFA</Status>
 </BankAccountDTOForStatus>
 <BankAccountDTOForStatus>
     <BankAccountID>3</BankAccountID>
     <Status>FrozenSB</Status>
 </BankAccountDTOForStatus>
</root>'

DECLARE @handle INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @InputXML

SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML(@handle, '/root/BankAccountDTOForStatus', 1)
WITH    (
            BankAccountID INT 'BankAccountID/text()',
            Status VARCHAR(128) 'Status/text()'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

- define your input XML - e.g. as a string
- convert that to a `XDocument`
- pass the `XDocument.Root` into the ParseXML method on your Linq-to-SQL data context

So your code would be something like this:

```
// define input XML - e.g. load from file or whatever
string xmlInput =
            @"<ArrayOfBankAccountDTOForStatus>
                         <BankAccountDTOForStatus>
                             <BankAccountID>2</BankAccountID>
                             <Status>FrozenFA</Status>
                         </BankAccountDTOForStatus>
                         <BankAccountDTOForStatus>
                             <BankAccountID>3</BankAccountID>
                             <Status>FrozenSB</Status>
                         </BankAccountDTOForStatus>
                     </ArrayOfBankAccountDTOForStatus>";

// convert that into a XDocument
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);

// using your DataContext - call ParseXML
using (DataClasses1DataContext ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var result = ctx.ParseXML(doc.Root);
}
```

And that's it! Now your XML is being passed to the stored procedure and dealt with there.